# Okta Verify 2FA authentication for Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, wine, two-factor-authentication

Under a new security policy, my company is forcing employees to install [Okta Verify](https://www.okta.com/integrations/okta-verify/) on all devices for 2FA authentication. Up until now, I've been happily using Ubuntu and authenticating via the Okta Android app's generated 2FA codes.

When logging in to our internal Github or other systems, the browser prompts me to open the locally installed Okta Verify app to authenticate (see attached screenshot). However, Okta Verify has [no supported Linux version](https://help.okta.com/eu/en-us/content/topics/end-user/ov-overview.htm).

Okta Verify prompt:

[image: Okta Verify prompt screenshot]

I fear the inevitable that I must return to Windows. Has anybody found a way to install Okta Verify on Linux? Could the Windows version possibly be installed on Ubuntu using Wine?

Comment: As we determined in comments here that have since been deleted, the primary challenge is obtaining an `.exe` file for Okta Verify on Windows desktop which can then be used with Wine.  One user posted a GitHub repo with an ostensible `.exe` for OV, but did not offer support for its authenticity before removing their contributions.

Comment: Maybe this NoMachine solution can help you 

[How to use Okta MFA with NoMachine on Linux](https://kb.nomachine.com/AR06S01134)

Comment: @lemrm Isn't the RADIUS server something that IT sets up on their end company-wide and to which my OV client connects to? I need to set up my own MFA server? I don't understand.

Comment: @lemrm I can't open that link, but D_AskUbuntu is probably correct.  NoMachine is a network access tool like TailScale, I can't imagine it can cause OV to be installed on my system.  That must be an administrative solution, not a user solution.

Comment: I'll just have to wait until Okta feels generous enough to develop a Linux client. Thanks anyway.